# Running "npm ci" when building docker image is much slower

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-for-windows, docker-desktop, npm-ci

I tried to run `npm ci` command using the same `package.json` and `package-lock.json` files in three different environments:

- docker host machine - takes **~27s** to complete
- inside a docker container - takes **~32s** to complete
- during building a docker image - takes **~163s** to complete

I wonder why it takes much more time to install packages when building an image. What the difference between running commands when building an image and when running commands inside a container manually? Perhaps it's related to the amount of resources (CPU, Memory) docker uses when building an image?

I use the same node and npm version in all three environments. Docker host is a Windows Server 2019 VM that has 2 virtual CPUs and 2GB of memory. Docker version is `18.09.2`.

Comment: "inside a docker container": was the `node_modules` directory located on a _docker volume_ or was it on the container file system itself?

Comment: @Thomasleveil it's on the container file system. I tried to replicate behaviour of building an image. If I correctly understand running commands inside container and then calling `docker commit` is not that different from the process of building an image (considering there is no image cache). Please, correct me if I'm wrong.
My another theory is that it runs that slow because of the image caching  process. If that's the case I'd like somebody to confirm it.

Comment: beware that the image produced by `docker commit` won't have the files that are located in a _docker volume_ in the container. Writing files to the docker file system is known to be slower than writing files on a docker volume, hence my previous question. CPU and memory: nope, AFAIK there is no limitation while building an image. It might be quicker in a container if you run `npm ci` multiple time due to npm modules caching